# Are there any caveats of using a git repository inside another git repository? Is it considered as a good practice?

Tags: git, repository-design

(I know there are some similar questions but I think none apply exactly to this one, so I decided to ask it.)

I never did repository nesting myself, but I'm in a situation that it would become handy. I just would like to know if there is any kind of know caveat it can cause that later would add difficulties for the main repository administration.

Also, in case it's okay to do that (repositories inside a repository), I would like to know if there is any kind of guide or specific repository configuration to achieve that without later problems.

thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you referring to git submodules, or just literally having git repositories existing inside another?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the two repositories does not track the same file then you're all good.

Just add the directory where the 'child' repository is in into the .gitignore file of the 'parent' repository so that the parent repository ignores everything inside the child repository.